# R - Extract city name from two-word strings

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am working with a database containing city names like this:

```
cities <- c("Fairhope 3NE", "Gadsden 19N", "Selma 13 WNW", "Batesville 8 WNW", 
"Elgin 5 S", "Tucson 11 W", "Williams 35 NNW", "Fallbrook 5 NE", 
"Stovepipe Wells 1 SW", "Cortez 8 SE", "La Junta 17 WSW", "Montrose 11 ENE", 
"Everglades City 5 NE", "Sebring 23 SSE", "Brunswick 23 S", "Newton 11 SW", 
"Newton 8 W", "Watkinsville 5 SSE", "Des Moines 17 E", "Champaign 9 SW", 
"Shabbona 5 NNE", "Bedford 5 WNW", "Manhattan 6 SSW", "Oakley 19 SSW", 
"Bowling Green 21 NNE", "Versailles 3 NNW", "Lafayette 13 SE", 
"Monroe 26 N", "Goodridge 12 NNW", "Chillicothe 22 ENE", "Joplin 24 N", 
"Salem 10 W", "Holly Springs 4 N", "Newton 5 ENE", "Asheville 13 S", 
"Asheville 8 SSW", "Durham 11 W", "Jamestown 38 WSW", "Medora 7 E", 
"Northgate 5 ESE", "Harrison 20 SSE", "Lincoln 11 SW", "Lincoln 8 ENE", 
"Whitman 5 ENE", "Las Cruces 20 N", "Los Alamos 13 W", "Socorro 20 N", 
"Mercury 3 SSW", "Coshocton 8 NNE", "Goodwell 2 E", "Stillwater 2 W", 
"Stillwater 5 WNW", "Coos Bay 8 SW", "Corvallis 10 SSW", "Riley 10 WSW", 
"Blackville 3 W", "McClellanville 7 NE", "Aberdeen 35 WNW", "Buffalo 13 ESE", 
"Pierre 24 S", "Sioux Falls 14 NNE", "Crossville 7 NW", "Austin 33 NW", 
"Bronte 11 NNE", "Edinburg 17 NNE", "Monahans 6 ENE", "Muleshoe 19 S", 
"Palestine 6 WNW", "Panther Junction 2 N", "Necedah 5 WNW")
```

And I want to extract only the city name. The following code works for some cases:

```
gsub( " .*$", "", cities)
```

but it fails for cities with two-word names, like for example `Stovepipe Wells 1 SW` and `La Junta 17 WSW`.

Any ideas of solutions for those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each string ends in the same pattern:

- space
- digit(s)
- optional space,
- combination of `ENSW`

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TVRNb9pAEL3zK0ZWD4nSSsEOCZEqVeCQRBHQqK7KoelhsBd7xbKLdtdQ@ufprHfXycGy/DQfb968sT6fS245M/D1C5QXySNy3ag9g2w5Sz5D8oSVqZiE4f3SfRZM7BCGGayWK/c9RcvMgQvBYBywQTITNZcwgsJF/GxLoyh/CF3CimI57gxkI1j6Go8oxFortaWUrukgKaw6sD0nGismhIEhFF1orrRl/6hV0ZGbI7y00hKhO1j5iIWSVivDXMNZqDY7MF0LrGjInNtTbEPDrDWXNaQZFL7gVLfSHHm57TCHLNnRevqFHy4A4zAO2i2XQYFRLPNAnRaKS3oRsw7KG9ztkdcS7mOlosH1Wkl0fDyhKas2SlcEBHkXKBu0FiXcUu0O@o5bwU60jwAMkqk6CjfGk2a0qHQYq/1i2qAjRmJHree4wROzlrkdFl4ekkwrBuktdCt@UqrSvKopJI1peePWVirbUFwahE1e1J4aQ3rTJdJAKNgOhtdemmclxAmKvZPYgI@J6o1iiYlpmBdv6AUffIDGceaHVpN8vYdecMeMVUcJ2bjfO6uURvBq05bIKE1N5nSt/FKeUWvurJhexz3NuSyVeN9uD4x776wabnf4gfEcyUW6LUlVKtQNNVcGJgJ39HKX0VlLlUprFUNIZKbLVp8gizPlyjSq9FYKC3PKH8nvkHrPFJZkONIQmpDgmXeoN0muqPEUT06veCUHuilu3C5Cux@8c8110ItcI7Dcep0D50WZC@qO0qN34Uoma6Yr56ys7zhtNxsUyk07CyZ65Uxr5rzQnU3BVfsX3GUTiZs4YE6XafrqXalJayx5KMsg/Dymmi64O9@QNKu4XLe6dqcUIHIsNigNXUXYyqIlmzfkYncXnhCZ0ZVmFBRov6IkA2v3zygtd06IpixZhU1Q9HJQm3Z9kcDbW3UF337PlsXqz9UnF0iP/1lens//AQ)

```
gsub(" \\d+ ?[ENSW]+$", "", cities)
```

Result:

```
 [1] "Fairhope"         "Gadsden"          "Selma"            "Batesville"      
 [5] "Elgin"            "Tucson"           "Williams"         "Fallbrook"       
 [9] "Stovepipe Wells"  "Cortez"           "La Junta"         "Montrose"        
[13] "Everglades City"  "Sebring"          "Brunswick"        "Newton"          
[17] "Newton"           "Watkinsville"     "Des Moines"       "Champaign"       
[21] "Shabbona"         "Bedford"          "Manhattan"        "Oakley"          
[25] "Bowling Green"    "Versailles"       "Lafayette"        "Monroe"          
[29] "Goodridge"        "Chillicothe"      "Joplin"           "Salem"           
[33] "Holly Springs"    "Newton"           "Asheville"        "Asheville"       
[37] "Durham"           "Jamestown"        "Medora"           "Northgate"       
[41] "Harrison"         "Lincoln"          "Lincoln"          "Whitman"         
[45] "Las Cruces"       "Los Alamos"       "Socorro"          "Mercury"         
[49] "Coshocton"        "Goodwell"         "Stillwater"       "Stillwater"      
[53] "Coos Bay"         "Corvallis"        "Riley"            "Blackville"      
[57] "McClellanville"   "Aberdeen"         "Buffalo"          "Pierre"          
[61] "Sioux Falls"      "Crossville"       "Austin"           "Bronte"          
[65] "Edinburg"         "Monahans"         "Muleshoe"         "Palestine"       
[69] "Panther Junction" "Necedah"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was the accepted one because a) it works and b) it was the first one (according to SO reported times).

Answer (score 3):

You may remove all substrings starting with a digit:

```
> sub("\\s*\\d.*", "", cities)
 [1] "Fairhope"         "Gadsden"          "Selma"            "Batesville"       "Elgin"            "Tucson"           "Williams"         "Fallbrook"        "Stovepipe Wells" 
[10] "Cortez"           "La Junta"         "Montrose"         "Everglades City"  "Sebring"          "Brunswick"        "Newton"           "Newton"           "Watkinsville"    
[19] "Des Moines"       "Champaign"        "Shabbona"         "Bedford"          "Manhattan"        "Oakley"           "Bowling Green"    "Versailles"       "Lafayette"       
[28] "Monroe"           "Goodridge"        "Chillicothe"      "Joplin"           "Salem"            "Holly Springs"    "Newton"           "Asheville"        "Asheville"       
[37] "Durham"           "Jamestown"        "Medora"           "Northgate"        "Harrison"         "Lincoln"          "Lincoln"          "Whitman"          "Las Cruces"      
[46] "Los Alamos"       "Socorro"          "Mercury"          "Coshocton"        "Goodwell"         "Stillwater"       "Stillwater"       "Coos Bay"         "Corvallis"       
[55] "Riley"            "Blackville"       "McClellanville"   "Aberdeen"         "Buffalo"          "Pierre"           "Sioux Falls"      "Crossville"       "Austin"          
[64] "Bronte"           "Edinburg"         "Monahans"         "Muleshoe"         "Palestine"        "Panther Junction" "Necedah"         
>
```

Here,

- `\\s*` - matches 0+ whitespace
- `\\d` - a digit
- `.*` - the rest of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lpPVeP/1). The `sub` only performs a single match and replace operation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
gsub("(\\D+)\\s+.*", "\\1", cities)
```

yielding

```
 [1] "Fairhope"         "Gadsden"          "Selma"            "Batesville"       "Elgin"           
 [6] "Tucson"           "Williams"         "Fallbrook"        "Stovepipe Wells"  "Cortez"          
[11] "La Junta"         "Montrose"         "Everglades City"  "Sebring"          "Brunswick"       
[16] "Newton"           "Newton"           "Watkinsville"     "Des Moines"       "Champaign"       
[21] "Shabbona"         "Bedford"          "Manhattan"        "Oakley"           "Bowling Green"   
[26] "Versailles"       "Lafayette"        "Monroe"           "Goodridge"        "Chillicothe"     
[31] "Joplin"           "Salem"            "Holly Springs"    "Newton"           "Asheville"       
[36] "Asheville"        "Durham"           "Jamestown"        "Medora"           "Northgate"       
[41] "Harrison"         "Lincoln"          "Lincoln"          "Whitman"          "Las Cruces"      
[46] "Los Alamos"       "Socorro"          "Mercury"          "Coshocton"        "Goodwell"        
[51] "Stillwater"       "Stillwater"       "Coos Bay"         "Corvallis"        "Riley"           
[56] "Blackville"       "McClellanville"   "Aberdeen"         "Buffalo"          "Pierre"          
[61] "Sioux Falls"      "Crossville"       "Austin"           "Bronte"           "Edinburg"        
[66] "Monahans"         "Muleshoe"         "Palestine"        "Panther Junction" "Necedah"
```

---

Explained, this says:

```
(\\D+) # not a digit, 1+ times
\\s+   # at least one whitespace
.*     # rest of the string
```

This is then replaced by the first captured group, `\\1` in this case.

Comment: So I thought "what if a city has a numeric character in the name?". It's not common (at all) but apparently, some Russian cities used to have numerics in them [`Krasnoyask-26`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheleznogorsk,_Krasnoyarsk_Krai). Many [closed cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city) did this. Just thought it was an interesting read!

Comment: @ctwheels: I did not know this. However, OP's cities do look American to me, don't they? Could be Canadian as well...

Comment: Oh I completely agree and your answer is a good one (and simple), I was obviously just trying to break it and discovered that, thought it was interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
gsub( " [1-9].*$", "", cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work anywhere, including R: `.+?(?=\ \d)`

It includes everything up to the first space followed by a digit.